# angular.json setup for multiple i18n locales

Tags: angular, angular-i18n

I have my project setup to build for two locales, each at their own url (via `configuration.<locale>.baseRef`). This is working fine for building the project (via `ng build`), although this setup has rendered my development server unusable. If I try to run `npm start`, I get the following error:

`An unhandled exception occurred: The development server only supports localizing a single locale per build`

This makes it so that I have to remove a build name from the `projects.<app-name>.architect.build.options.localize` option (the development server will start with that setting at `["en-US"]`, but not `["en-US", "es-ES"]`)

I understand that it is verbose, but I have included the entirety of angular.json below. I do not understand which pieces need to be adjusted to allow building multiple distributable directories while still allowing for a simple development server

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "console": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "i18n": {
        "sourceLocale": "en-US",
        "locales": {
          "es-ES": "src/assets/i18n/messages.es-ES.xlf"
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "localize": ["en-US" ,"es-ES"],
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "./extra-webpack.config.js",
              "replaceDuplicatePlugins": true
            },
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/c3/c3.min.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "es-ES": {
              "outputPath": "dist/es-ES/",
              "i18nLocale": "es-ES",
              "i18nFile": "src/assets/i18n/messages.es-ES.xlf",
              "baseHref": "/es-ES/"
            },
            "en-US": {
              "outputPath": "dist/en-US/",
              "baseHref": "/en-US/"
            },
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "./extra-webpack.config.js",
              "replaceDuplicatePlugins": true
            },
            "browserTarget": "console:build:en-US"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "es-ES": {
              "browserTarget": "console:build:es-ES"
            },
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "console:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "console:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "scripts": [],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "console-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e",
      "sourceRoot": "e2e",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "./protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "console:serve"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "console",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "prefix": "app",
      "style": "scss"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": "app"
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": "62782045-42a1-4d0f-b379-e9a856db628d"
  }
}
```

Comment: I think that the problem is the line `"localize": ["en-US" ,"es-ES"],`, try remove it

Comment: @brian, I am facing the same issue, would you recommend a solution to switch "localize" config between dev and prod environments?

Comment: @PratibhaGupta My solution to develop with all languages present was to spin up multiple dev servers inside containers using docker compose. Additionally, there is an nginx container that is proxying traffic to each of the locales using the `configuration.<locale>.baseRef` setting

Answer (score 2):

[Angular's doc](https://angular.io/guide/i18n#generate-application-versions-for-each-locale) says the problem is because you've specified more than one localize and haven't provided an override during development. Add `"development": { "localize": ["en-US"], ...}` under `projects > console > architect > build` to allow you to build multiple localizations while being able to serve as well. The cool thing is you can swap out "en-US" with your other localization to test that as well. :)

> Due to the deployment complexities of i18n and the need to minimize rebuild time, the development server only supports localizing a single locale at a time. If you set the "localize" option to true, define more than one locale, and use ng serve; then an error occurs. If you want to develop against a specific locale, set the "localize" option to a specific locale.
> For example, for French (fr), specify "localize": ["fr"].